# Accessing cells of a cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, element

I wanted to post images for my question, but since I still don't have the 10 reputation, I couldn't do so.

My question is that I have a `cell` of size `128x128`. For such cell, how can I retrieve all the `128x128` elements?

Comment: Upload your images to a site such as imgur, then add the links to them by editing the question or by adding them in a comment.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Do you have a cell array of size 128 x 128 elements?  What is contained within each cell?  A matrix? A vector? You can't just access any cell array through `c{x,y}` where `c` is your cell array and `x,y` is the location of the cell?  This is a bit confusing.  What do you want to do with this cell array specifically?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like this.

```
a=[1,2,3]

a =

     1     2     3

>> b=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

b =

     1     2     3     4     5     6

>> c=ones(3,5)

c =

     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1

>> d={a,b,c}

d = 

    [1x3 double]    [1x6 double]    [3x5 double]

>> d{1,1}

ans =

     1     2     3
```

A simple `for loop` can suffice.. No??

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking in my opinion... then again, none of us do lol.  I believe the OP already has a cell array and wants to access certain elements or all of them simultaneously.... but I honestly can't decrypt what the OP really wants.